# Scala scheduling for a fixed interval between runs

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to poll a database on an interval. To avoid server load a main concern is avoiding overlapping runs *as well as runs not evenly spaced on the time axis*; Which would otherwise occur with a naive timer scheme.

Differently put: I would like to have a fixed interval between a run's end and the next one's start time.

Trying to avoid Actors just because of the code boilerplate that they bring in, I have tried this below. Maybe there is a better or just simpler way.

```
  /* 
   * Infinite scheduling for acquiring a database snapshot at an almost fixed interval.
   * The actual effective acquisition interval is (duration of the acquisition + dbSyncIntervalSecs)  
   */

  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent.blocking
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val system = ActorSystem("MySystem") // make global if more things hinge on the actor system

  val interval = Configuration.dbSyncIntervalSecs

  private def acquireLoop: Unit = {
    Future { 
      blocking { 
        println("about to sync from database")
        acquire
      }
    }
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(interval seconds)(acquireLoop)
  }
```

Any advice?

Thread pool looks healthy though:

[image]

Also, should I better use a separate execution context of a certain kind for this ongoing process, rather than piggyback the default one with the `blocking` idiom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although you've stated you don't want to because of boilerplate, a simple actor using `scheduleOnce` is a good way to do this, and the boilerplate doesn't seem that bad:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props, ActorSystem}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val interval = 3 seconds
val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor{
  override def preStart = self ! "Execute"
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "Execute" =>
      println(s"Executing at ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(interval, self, "Execute")(context.dispatcher)
  }}))
```

Very few lines of code to get the exact result required.

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" [`schedule` method](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.actor.Scheduler@schedule(initialDelay:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,interval:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)(f:=%3EUnit)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):akka.actor.Cancellable) guarantees want you want - the submitted `=> Unit` block only runs in a one-at-a-time fashion.

Quoting from the docs:

> Schedules a function to be run repeatedly with an initial delay and a
>   frequency. E.g. if you would like the function to be run after 2
>   seconds and thereafter every 100ms you would set delay = Duration(2,
>   TimeUnit.SECONDS) and interval = Duration(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
>   If the execution of the function takes longer than the interval, the
>   subsequent execution will start immediately after the prior one
>   completes **(there will be no overlap of the function executions)**.

*(emph mine)*

EDIT: you now mentioned you want **a fixed time *between runs* *as well***. Well, an expedient alternative is **to simply use the Java API's [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)**:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, **and subsequently with the given delay
>   between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the
>   next.**

*(emph mine)*

Unfortunately, there's no direct equivalent to this method - neither in the Scala Library, nor in the Akka `Scheduler` API. Note that usage will require you to define your task as a `Runnable`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

*(Personally, I would use a simple actor with `scheduleOnce`, but you've mentioned you want to avoid them)*

Comment: Good to know. I still prefer to have a fixed interval between their end times, rather than have the timer run the next invocation right after the slow one finishes. I would like invocations evenly spaced at all times. So this does not (seem to) avoid the question, as I see it.

Comment: @matanster : OK, having a *hard time interval* _between runs_ is another problem.

Comment: Correct, apologies, and I've edited the question now to explicitly center around that intent. Sorry for being very implicit before and thanks for the relevant documentation quote!

Comment: @matanster : no problem. Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Differently put: I would like to have a fixed interval between a run's end and the next one's start time.

Ehm, so you want just:

```
while(true) {
    doThing()
    Thread.sleep(fixedTimeBetweenEndAndStart)
}
```

It would be nicer to have it in tail recursion funstion and to handle correctly Thread.isInterrupted/interrupted exception through.